# Does a counterexample always disprove a conjecture?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, conjectures

I'm sincerely confused on this topic (the title). I was wondering if a counterexample always disproved a conjecture. I'm leaning towards true because it's not really a counterexample if it evaluates to false... right? Any insight or help would be dearly appreciated.

Comment: are you confused on what the definition of a counterexample is ? ( asking mostly to see where you may be stuck and to possibly add more appropriate truer audience tags.

Comment: My definition of a counterexample is a statement that disproves a conjecture. @RoddyMacPhee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A counterexample always disproves conjectures.  A conjecture will suppose that something is true for different cases, but if you find an example where it is not, the conjecture must be modified to not include a particular case or rejected.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! This clears things up a bit.